# 5 Minute intervals of my data in R

Tags: r

I have tried everything but cannot find anything that works for my data.

I have 80,000 lines of data and I want to write some code the will average every 5 lines and obviously in turn have 5 times less lines of code.

```
                timestamp curr_proc_units entitled_cycles capped_cycles
1481000580 2016-12-05 23:03:00               1       512269820      17400328
1481000640 2016-12-05 23:04:00               1       511754172      15196426
1481000700 2016-12-05 23:05:00               1       512715413      17452370
1481000760 2016-12-05 23:06:00               1       512334707     124006106
1481000820 2016-12-05 23:07:00               1       510737517      34001018
1481000880 2016-12-05 23:08:00               1       512152279      15343897
       uncapped_cycles
1481000580       47532.200
1481000640        9154.117
1481000700       45975.650
1481000760     4018213.067
1481000820      145820.350
1481000880       41980.917
```

Comment: So in the data you are showing here, the time stamps are very nice and consistent. Is this always the case? Does the 5th line always come in on the minute? Is it important to differentiate by time here? Also, is there a reason beyond file management to reduce the amount of data here?

Comment: Yes they are all 1 min intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(grp = cut(timestamp, breaks = "5 min"))]
```

Comment: Thanks I shall try that out

Comment: setDT(rra)[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(grp = cut(timestamp, by = "5 min")]  I get an error Error: unexpected ']' in "setDT(rra)[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(grp = cut(timestamp, by = "5 min")]"

Comment: @KathrynWithers  There was a typo, I forgot the `)`.  Fixed now

Comment: Thank you but I now get this error: Error in cut.POSIXt(timestamp, by = "5 min") :
  argument "breaks" is missing, with no default
Calls: [ -> [.data.table -> eval -> eval -> cut -> cut.POSIXt

Comment: @KathrynWithers  Sorry, the argument of `cut` is `breaks` and not `by`.

Comment: Thank you @akrun that works now really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, group = cut(timestamp, breaks = "5 min")) %>% 
  summarize_all(funs(mean(.)))
```

Comment: You can reduce one step by creating the `group` in `group_by`

Comment: I get this error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  argument "breaks" is missing, with no default
Calls: %>% ... as.data.frame -> mutate_ -> mutate_.tbl_df -> mutate_impl -> .Call

Comment: Thank you very much